# Rails Model Relationship Suggestion Needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm building my first Rails project and it's a checkout system for a computer loaner pool.  Creating `Technicians` (who perform checkouts) and `CheckOuts` (like transactions) makes perfect sense.  However, I'm struggling with the relationship between `CheckOuts` and `LoanerComputers`.

`Technician` and `CheckOut` have a 1:N relationship, and `CheckOut` and `LoanerComputer`have a 1:1 relationship.  I believe in my Rails-n00b heart that it would be nice to have association proxy, e.g. `Technician.check_outs.loaner_computers` or even better `Technician.loaner_computers`, but from what I've learned that would mean that my `LoanerComputer` class must contain the `belongs_to`, and that assumes that the `LoanerComputer` table in my database has a `check_out_id` column.

I've tried thinking about it from a "rental" approach, but I see lots of solutions that have a fourth model to store state changes of the thing being "rented." To me, it makes more sense to have `technician_id` and `loaner_computer_id` in a single `CheckOut` entry, but then how could I easily access a technician's checked-out loaner computers using association proxy?  Is it possible to use `:delegate` in this instance, or does it look like I'd have to make a custom method to read loaner computers via technicians?  Here's example code:

```
class Technician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :check_outs
end

class CheckOut < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :technician

  # has_one :loaner_computer
  #   OR
  # belongs_to :loaner_computer (which means I need to have a "loaner_id" column in the db, right?)
end

class LoanerComputer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # belongs_to :check_out (which means I need to have a "check_out_id" column in the db)
  #   OR
  # has_one :check_out
end
```

P.S. Do I just have it all backwards?  Should I say `Technicians` `has_many` `LoanerComputers`, and `LoanerComputers` `has_many` `CheckOuts`?

Thanks for your time! Let me know if anything needs clarification!

Comment: If you're finding it hard to get an association to do what you want, you could try scopes. They wouldn't allow a loaner to be assigned directly to a technician, but that wouldn't seem to make sense anyway. Either way, please can you describe the role of a 'Loaner'? I'm not sure I understand what it represents.

Comment: I'm wondering if what you're really after is a "Has Many Through" relationship. That is, a Technician Has Many Loaners Through Checkout. And a Loaner can ask the Checkout Join Table, for the Technician. It's a rather different way to think about it, which, if you're new to Rails associations, you might not immediately think of.

Comment: @AFaderDarkly Edited my question and changed "Loaner" to "LoanerComputer."  As a tech, I would take a loaner computer from the available pool and check it out for a customer.

Comment: @JezC my understanding of `has_many :through` is that it's like chaining `has_many` between models.  however, the `CheckOuts` and `Loaners` have a 1:1 relationship (a checkout can't have multiple loaner computers, and a loaner computer can only be part of one check out at a time). can you do a `has_many :through` via a 1:1 relationship?

Comment: Don't worry about the counts. That's a validation issue (one machine can not be loaned out twice). And if you really need it, there is a "Has One Through" - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association

Comment: I would have thought that if you were modelling the computers themselves (LoanerComputer) then a computer can be loaned out multiple times in its lifetime, thus there is a 1:many relationship between LoanerComputers and Checkouts. Unless I am mistaken, or checkouts are destroyed after completion.

Comment: @AFaderDarkly Right, and maybe that's exactly where I'm confused.  It's very possible I was trying to let the Rails convention do the validation for me by association ("A loaner can only be a part of a single check-out at any given time, so it would be 1:1.")  The more I think about it, it does make sense to say `LoanerComputers` `has_many` `CheckOuts`...

Comment: Yes, good - validation concerning current loan-outs should be done separately from the association. The association doesn't care about time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, what you're looking for - is "has_many through" association.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

In Your case - It'll look like this

```
class Technician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :check_outs
  has_many :loaners, through: :check_outs
end

class CheckOut < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Must have technician_id and check_out_id fields in DB
  belongs_to :technician
  belongs_to :check_out
end

class Loaner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :technicians, through: :check_outs
end
```

With this - You'll be able to access loaners from technician and reverse

```
Technician.loaners
Loaner.technicians
```

You can also access check_outs from both models

Comment: This looks good - only you'll need a `has_many :checkouts` on Loaner for completeness. It does break from the original spec of there being a 1:1 relationship between Checkouts and Loaners, but from the comments it sounds like that spec is a mistake anyway.

Comment: @AFaderDarkly My thoughts exactly.